# How to patch a function in x64 assembly to always return true

Tags: assembly, x86-64, patch, mach-o

I'm trying to patch a function in CoreBrightness.framework of macOS to always return true. After hours of hopeless attempts, I really need some help.

The function is as followed (from IDA 7):

```
__text:0000000000036CFA ; char __cdecl -[KeyboardBrightnessClient isKeyboardBuiltIn:](KeyboardBrightnessClient *self, SEL, unsigned __int64)
__text:0000000000036CFA __KeyboardBrightnessClient_isKeyboardBuiltIn__ proc near
__text:0000000000036CFA                                         ; DATA XREF: __objc_const:0000000000080BE8↓o
// skipped
__text:0000000000036D94
__text:0000000000036D94 loc_36D94:                              ; CODE XREF: -[KeyboardBrightnessClient isKeyboardBuiltIn:]+81↑j
__text:0000000000036D94                 xor     ebx, ebx
__text:0000000000036D96
__text:0000000000036D96 loc_36D96:                              ; CODE XREF: -[KeyboardBrightnessClient isKeyboardBuiltIn:]+98↑j
__text:0000000000036D96                 mov     rdi, r14
__text:0000000000036D99                 call    cs:_objc_release_ptr
__text:0000000000036D9F                 movzx   eax, bl
__text:0000000000036DA2                 pop     rbx
__text:0000000000036DA3                 pop     r14
__text:0000000000036DA5                 pop     rbp
__text:0000000000036DA6                 retn
__text:0000000000036DA7 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__text:0000000000036DA7
__text:0000000000036DA7 loc_36DA7:                              ; CODE XREF: -[KeyboardBrightnessClient isKeyboardBuiltIn:]+57↑j
__text:0000000000036DA7                 mov     rdi, r14
__text:0000000000036DAA                 mov     rsi, rbx
__text:0000000000036DAD                 call    __KeyboardBrightnessClient_isKeyboardBuiltIn___cold_1 ; -[KeyboardBrightnessClient isKeyboardBuiltIn:].cold.1
__text:0000000000036DB2                 jmp     short loc_36D53
__text:0000000000036DB2 __KeyboardBrightnessClient_isKeyboardBuiltIn__ endp
```

The full version is at https://pastebin.com/UYG1sRx9

Comment: Storing a non-zero value in `rax` should cause the function to return true. But you need to be careful when editing this binary, because instruction alignment is key. In x64 instructions are different byte lengths, so you'll need to find a way to change an instruction without modifying the byte count of the function in a way that causes a crash.

Comment: If you want it to skip everything and just return, change 36cfa to “mov eax, 1; ret” [b8 01 00 00 00 c3].

Comment: If you want the function to still do all the steps that it currently does, and just change the return value, change 36d92 to “nop; nop; mov bl, 1” [90 90 b3 01]. (bl gets moved into eax after the final function call.)